# Python - why can `int(x, 2)` only be used on strings, but not on integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, int

I have this example code:

```
test = 1011
test2 = int(test, 2)
print(test2)
```

which will throw an error saying

```
int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

The code works when i wrap `test` into `str()`, since the int-conversion needs a string as an input.

My question: Why is that so, and is there no easy way to convert on bases while accepting int? I find it rather counter-intuitive that an interger conversion method requires a string as an input.

Comment: `1011` is already the numeric value *one thousand eleven*. It's *not* "one zero one one". What if you wrote `0o1763` instead, the same value in octal notation. That would make for some weird conversion…

Answer (score 3):

**Because applying it to integers makes no sense**

In your example `test` is a number. It has no base. All numbers are like this: binary 0x1011, decimal 11 and hexadecimal 0x0B are the *exact same number*. The three ways of writing it are just different ways of writing down the same thing, just as using the Chinese character for 3, 三, would be. Internally, of course, in computers numbers represented in binary - e.g. `0b1111110011` - but can be displayed in any base you like. Bases are only relevant when converting a number to, or from, a string.

However, if you wanted to set `test` using a binary representation you could simply write:

```
test = 0b1011
```

Comment: That makes sense, the conversion wouldnt know where to convert from if i dont pass a base for the input, i guess it works with `str(1101)` because it assumes that, when i dont add a base, the number is decimal?

Comment: @FlyingThunder: Correct, since decimal is the most common format, the string-to-int conversion assumes that is what you are using unless you tell it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

This function only works on strings because the base is only relevant if you have a string representation of the number.

If you have an integer, there is no associated base, it's a number. And then, you can represent it as a string in base 2, 16 or 10 (or any other you want).